# python jinja template for insert statement

Tags: python, jinja2

Have an sql query:

```
insert into my_schema.table1(
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
    f4
) values (%s, %s, %s, %s)
```

And I need to create a jinja template for it. My suggestion is to create the following template:

```
insert into {{ mysql_schema }}.{{ table_name }} (
    {%- for feature in features %}
        {{ feature }} {{ "," if not loop.last }}
    {%- endfor %}
) values ({%- for feature in features %}
                {{ %s }} {{ "," if not loop.last }}
          {%- endfor %}
)
```

But in this case I get an error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '%'
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

You should output `%s` literally, rather than letting Jinja2 evaluate it by enclosing it in double curly braces, resulting in the said syntax error.

Change:

```
                {{ %s }} {{ "," if not loop.last }}
```

to:

```
                %s{{ ", " if not loop.last }}
```